# Checking a url for a 404 error scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-status-code-404, scrapy

I'm going through a set of pages and I'm not certain how many there are, but the current page is represented by a simple number present in the url (e.g. "http://www.website.com/page/1")

I would like to use a for loop in scrapy to increment the current guess at the page and stop when it reaches a 404. I know the response that is returned from the request contains this information, but I'm not sure how to automatically get a response from a request.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Currently my code is something along the lines of :

```
def start_requests(self):
    baseUrl = "http://website.com/page/"
    currentPage = 0
    stillExists = True
    while(stillExists):
        currentUrl = baseUrl + str(currentPage)
        test = Request(currentUrl)
        if test.response.status != 404: #This is what I'm not sure of
            yield test
            currentPage += 1
        else:
            stillExists = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib2

baseURL = "http://www.website.com/page/"

for n in xrange(100):
    fullURL = baseURL + str(n)
    #print fullURL
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(fullURL)
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        if resp.getcode() == 404:
            #Do whatever you want if 404 is found
            print ("404 Found!")
        else:
            #Do your normal stuff here if page is found.
            print ("URL: {0} Response: {1}".format(fullURL, resp.getcode()))
    except:
        print ("Could not connect to URL: {0} ".format(fullURL))
```

This iterates through the range and attempts to connect to each URL via `urllib2`. I don't know `scapy` or how your example function opens the URL but this is an example with how to do it via `urllib2`.

Note that most sites that utilize this type of URL format are normally running a CMS that can automatically redirect non-existent pages to a custom `404 - Not Found` page which will still show up as a HTTP status code of 200. In this case, the best way to look for a page that may show up but is actually just the custom 404 page, you should do some screen scraping and look for anything that may not appear during a "normal" page return such as text that says "Page not found" or something similar and unique to the custom 404 page.

Comment: In my experience, most custom 404 pages do return a 404 status code.

Comment: Turns out that theirs didn't, and I can't really solve this problem without checking their contents which makes it too slow, but this answer would have solved things normally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *yield/return* the request in order to check the status, creating a `Request` object does not actually send it.

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'website.com'
    baseUrl = "http://website.com/page/"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.baseUrl + '0')

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status != 404:
            page = response.meta.get('page', 0) + 1
            return Request('%s%s' % (self.baseUrl, page), meta=dict(page=page))
```