# How to check if a url is valid in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a list of url and many of them are invalid. When I use scrapy to crawl, the engine will automatically filter those urls with 404 status code, but some urls' status code aren't 404 and will be crawled so when I open it, it says something like there's nothing here or the domain has been changed, etc. Can someone let me know how to filter these types of invalid urls?

Comment: `if requests.post(url).status_code !=200: print(error) `

Comment: Hi, this is not what I am asking. The Scrapy already filtered those urls with status code not equal to 200. What I am asking is that how to check other types of invalid url. Those that can be actually opened, but nothing in there or show some error messages. Thank you :)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865611/checking-a-url-for-a-404-error-scrapy

Answer (score 1):

I already did a project that's how the code was

In your parse function

```
def parse(self, response):
    if response.status == 200:
        #do what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in list_data:
    if requests.get(i).status_code!=200:
        print error
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your callback (e.g. `parse`) implement checks that detect those cases of 200 responses that are not valid, and exit the callback right away (`return`) when you detect one of those requests.